# how to pass path of folder image directory in argument parser to test all images on my folder instead of only one?

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, detection

My program is testing only one picture example_01.png, I want to test all images that I put in my folder examples
so how can I do that ?
thanks

```
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-f", "--face", type=str,
    default="face_detector",
    help="path to face detector model directory")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str,
    default="mask_detector.model",
    help="path to trained face mask detector model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load our serialized face detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face detector model...")
prototxtPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"], "deploy.prototxt"])
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"],
    "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

# load the face mask detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face mask detector model...")
model = load_model(args["model"])

# load the input image from disk, clone it, and grab the image spatial
# dimensions
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
orig = image.copy()
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
```

Call:

```
python detect_mask_image.py --image examples/example_01.png
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def main(args):
 # Prepare an image
    directory = 'example'
    img_path_list =[]
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        # checking if it is a file
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            print(f)
            # print(type)
            img_path_list.append(f)
    print(img_path_list)
    args.image = img_path_list
    print(args.image, "**") #list of Frames path
    print(args.image[0])
    print(type(args.image[0]))

    
    for i,j in enumerate(args.image):
        image = load_image(args.image[i], transform)
        image_tensor = image.to(device)
        
        # Generate an caption from the image
        feature = encoder(image_tensor)
        sampled_ids = decoder.sample(feature)
        sampled_ids = sampled_ids[0].cpu().numpy()          # (1, max_seq_length) -> (max_seq_length)
        
        # Convert word_ids to words
        captions = []
        sampled_caption = []
        for word_id in sampled_ids:
            word = vocab.idx2word[word_id]
            sampled_caption.append(word)
            if word == '<end>':
                break
        sentence = ' '.join(sampled_caption)
        
        # Print out the image and the generated caption
        print("*****************************************")
        print (sentence)
        captions.append(sentence)
        print("*****************************************")
        image = Image.open(args.image[i], "rb")
        plt.imshow(np.asarray(image))
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your code.

Comment: I think you forgot to remove the "solution:" at the begining of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try os.list_dir(pathName)?
By this function you can list all the photos which are present in a directory "path"

You can convert the result from this to list and loop through all the images!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys

# Open a file
path = "/var/www/html/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

# This would print all the files and directories
for file in dirs:
   print file
```

Code from - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm

Comment: path = 'Image Path'
# Using cv2.imread() method 
img = cv2.imread(path)

Comment: But i find problems with ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()